# User provided content in DocPad

Tags: node.js, docpad

I'm considering [DocPad](http://www.docpad.org/) to make a website with lots of user interaction like comments, user profiles etc. I like file based data storage, so I thought about writing data posted by users in files under src/documents/ (eg. src/documents/comments/*some-generated-id*.html.md and src/documents/users/*user-name*.html.md).

That would require some server side logic to process and store user input. How would you address that? Where shall I put my code? I suppose this should go to a plugin. Is there a ready plugin like that?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.

I made plugin under /plugins/userInput/userInput.plugin.coffee as described by @balupton here: http://bevry.me/docpad/plugin-write.

Inside my plugin I have this:

```
<!-- language: lang-coffee -->
module.exports = (BasePlugin) ->
  class userInput extends BasePlugin
    name: "userInput"
    serverExtend: (options) ->
      {server} = options
      docpad = @docpad
      server.delete '*', userInput.deleteContent
      server.get '*', (request, response, next) ->
        switch request.query.action
          when 'delete' then userInput.deleteContent request, response, next
          else next()
    @deleteContent: (request, response, next) ->
      response.send 'That was really cool shit, man. Now it\'s gone!'
```

This is just proof of concept. It doesn't really delete or change any content. Anyway that answers my question and from here it should be easy to implement real data manipulation. I'll share this plugin when it's a little more mature.

BTW DocPad is awesome. I was dreaming about something like this for long time. Thanks to all guys behind it.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You can also hook into events via your [docpad configuration file](http://bevry.me/docpad/config). [Check out this gist for an example.](https://gist.github.com/3695936)

Answer (score 0):

1) Any/all dynamic content should be "offshored" to some service provider. Like
ads to ad service (ok its done that way almost always)
comments to disqus or something similar
rss to any rss service out there

2) User profiles are not easy. (And unless you can not hook up with some 3rd party user profile service, like google+/facebook)

One solution would be to build server that handle all user generated content and then update static files for you.

That may be slow, and troublesome.